# How to block USB media on a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, autorun

I would like to block a USB device even if its drivers are installed on the computer. That is to say, I want to plugin the media and nothing happens so that a normal user is not allowed to see, write, or execute anything from this specific media, even if the drivers of the media are installed. Is it possible and how can it be done ?

I'm working on Windows 10 64-bit and I already tried to disallow autorun by changing the local policies but the USB media is still accessible when I plug the media in.

EDIT :

I enabled the "Turn off autoplay" policy in the local group policy editor (Computer Configuration/ Administrative Templates / Windows Components /autoplay Policies)

I also modified the policies in Computer Configuration/ Administrative Templates / System / Device Installation / Device Installation Restrictions . Here I enabled "Allow administrator to override device installation restrictions", "prevent installation of removable devices " and " prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings"

Comment: Would encryption be close enough (non-authorized user would see just gibberish if they could see anything at all)?  Since authorized people need some way to access it, what kind of scenario are you envisioning for how authorized users would access it?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the use of USB storage devices in Windows 10 by navigating to the following Group Policy hierarchy:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Removable Storage Access
```

Enable each **Removable Disks** policy to suit your needs:

[image: Local Group Policy Editor]

Source:  [How to Disable the Use of USB Storage Devices in Windows 10](https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/how-to-disable-use-of-usb-storage-devices-in-windows-10.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The thing is that I want to deny access only to specific usb keys. For now the GPO that repsponds the best to my desires is "Prevent installation of devices that match any of these device IDs" (in Computer Configuration/ Administrative Templates / System / Device Installation / Device Installation Restrictions and to tick the box "Also apply to matching devices that are already installed." But my problem with this solution is that the device IDs are the hardware ids and compatible IDs of the usb device which are not unique so I might block more usb devices than needed

Comment: If that's the case, you definitely have some very uncommon needs within this scenario.  Hopefully someone else can chime in with another potential solution.